windows cmd sort

?`ёёЁ
не сортирует, выводит ёёё
кто подскажет как отсортировать строки в файле по длинне, с учетом что sort не работает в системе

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

@aleksandrbarakin, эдя инфа ошибки

Полагаю, sort.exe работает, но не так, как Вы ожидаете. Касательно задачи: посмотрите этот ответ.

@OldSkull крч проблема оказалась в том что в сортируемом файле были нечитаемые символы \r, изза этого криво ратотает
